# Approximating $e$ with 2s and 3s

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, approximation-algorithms

How can I generate a series of 2s and 3s such that the average of the generated values (so far) is as close to $e$ as possible?

For example:

```
3:       avg=3      |2-e|    =0.282
3,2:     avg=2.5    |2.5-e|  =0.218
3,2,3:   avg=2.667  |2.667-e|=0.052
3,2,3,3: avg=2.75   |2.75-e| =0.032
```

Also, how can I *quickly* check if the $n$th index in the sequence is a 2 or 3?

Comment: This question is about an exact algorithm which computes the sequence which approximates e, not about an approximation algorithm.

Answer (score 13):

As Gerry points out, the sequence
$$
a_n = [n e] - [(n-1)e],
$$
where $[x]$ is the integer closest to $x$, has the desired extremal property. Unfortunately, one needs to know the value of $e$ to calculate the sequence in this way.

Fortunately, this is a typical example of a Sturmian sequence (on the alphabet $\{2,3\}$), and they can be generated quickly from the continued fraction expansion (of $e$, in this case). If one uses the floor function in place of rounding, this has already been worked out by Ken Stolarsky and Tom Brown, and you can find a simple proof in my article *[Fraenkel's Partition and Brown's Decomposition](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0305133)*, which was [published in Integers](http://math.colgate.edu/%7Eintegers/d11/d11.pdf) (pdf). This gives you quickly a large initial segment of the sequence; you cannot jump directly to $a_{1000000}$.

I haven't seen any detailed exposition using the "round" function (or ceiling function), but presumably it follows from the same principles.

A putman-ish followup question is to find a combinatorial process that generates a sequence $b_n$ with $\frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n b_i \to e$. I don't have an answer for that. Yet.

Comment: Presumably, one could use the nearest-integer version of the continued fraction [NICF] algorithm, but I don't know whether the NICF of $e$ has any pattern. 

Comment: There several different kind of constraint in terms of how well the limit is e. 1: increases strictly always to the limit, 2 : be as close as possible to the limit. In case 2 it is not clear if it should alternate? Nice interesting problem!

Comment: The NICF of $e$ is $[3,-4,\overline{-2,2k+5}]_{k=0}^\infty$, but I'm not sure how one could use it.

Answer (score 8):

Isn't the $n$ term just the closest integer to $ne$, minus the closest integer to $(n-1)e$?

Comment: Since you picked a number near $5!$.. we know that the fractional part of $n!e$ is very nearly $1/n$ and $e$ approximately $2 5/7$ is good enough to say that the fractional part of $123 e$ is about $1/5+15/7$ i.e. of $1/5+1/7$ adding $2 5/7$ to that means that we want a 3. But in general you need to know $e$ accurately enough find which way to round $ne$

Comment: @Ishamis, you want something simpler than calculating $124e$, rounding it to the nearest integer, calculating $123e$, rounding it to the nearest integer, and then subtracting the second integer from the first? 

Comment: Something simpler might be calculating 123e, saving the fractional as well as the integer part, and then using the fractional part of {e} plus the fractional part of 123e to determine which way to round.  But if you prefer multiplying... . Gerhard "Why Prefer Multiplication Over Addition" Paseman, 2011.03.03 

Answer (score 3):

To compute the $n$th term in this sequence, you really only need decent estimates on the fractional parts of $(n-1)e$ and $ne$ (following Gerry Myerson's solution) - you get 2 if and only if the fractional part of $(n-1)e$ lies in $[0.5,1)$ and the fractional part of $ne$ lies in $[0,0.5)$. To find the fractional parts, you typically need about $m$ large integer divisions, where $m$ is such that $m!$ is a bit larger than $n$.  A modern computer can do this quite quickly: SAGE took about 1 second to find that the $10^{100000}$th term is 3, and about 55 seconds to find that the $10^{1000000}$th term is also 3.

**Edit:** I'm still quite confused about Kevin O'Bryant's comments to the effect that knowledge of $e$ affects the operation count.  To direct the conversation, I'll include some SAGE code that computes which half of the unit interval contains the fractional part of $ne$.  An output of 0 means the fractional part lies in the lower half, while an output of 1 means it lies in the upper half.

> ```
> def fracpart(n):
>     ipart = n
>     fpart = 0
>     acc = 0
>     k = 1
>     while ipart != 0 or ceil(2*acc)-2*acc < 2/k:
>         (ipart,rem) = ipart.quo_rem(k)
>         fpart = RDF(rem/k + fpart/k)
>         acc = acc + fpart
>         if acc >= 1: acc = acc - 1
>         k = k + 1
>     return floor(2*acc)
> ```

The large integer divisions occur in the function `quo_rem`, while the other divisions are small.  This code will return the correct answer for all but less than one out of a billion of the reasonable inputs - the remaining cases (where floating point precision isn't good enough) can be dealt with by using high-precision reals, removing the letters "RDF" to switch to rationals, or using some modular arithmetic to work with remainders.

The code uses the fact that $e$ expands as a sum of reciprocals of factorials in an essential way, but there doesn't seem to be any point where it explicitly computes the number $e$ itself.  I'm not sure if this quality exempts the program from the previous criticism.

Comment: But you still need to know the value of $e$ in some form, either as a limit or as a continued fraction or...somehow.

Comment: Yes.  If we didn't have a rapidly converging series for $e$, it would be quite hopeless to find the $10^{1000000}$th term.  I'm not sure why it is problematic that we need the value of $e$.

Comment: Not problematic, but if we're counting operations, we should count those, too.

Answer (score 0):

Given a number $a\in[0,1)$ which is written in the form $a=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} s_k/2^k$ with $s_k\in\{0,1\}$ we want to find a sequence $\Sigma=(t_k)_{k=0}^{\infty}$ of $0$'s and $1$'s such that the average $(1/2^r)\sum_{k < 2^r} t_k$ converges to $a$ as $r$ goes to infinity.

To start things off, note that the integer part of $2^ra$ is $a_r=\sum_{1\leq k\leq r} s_k 2^{r-k}$ for some $r\geq 0$. We will inductively create a pattern $p_r$ of $0$'s and $1$'s of length $2^r$ such that there are *exactly* $a_r$ $1$'s in it.
Note that the pattern $p_0$ is just the pattern consisting of one $0$.

Since $a_r<2^r$, there is *at least* one $0$ in the pattern $p_r$.

Secondly, note that if we repeat the pattern $p_r$ *ad infinitum*, then the average we get is *exactly* $a_r/2^r$ as the limit.

We now want to inductively extend this to a pattern $p_{r+1}$. Take a second copy of $p_r$ as the pattern $q_{r+1}$. Note that the pattern $q_{r+1}$ has *at least one* $0$.

If $s_{r+1}$ is $0$, then keep $q_{r+1}$ as it is. If $s_{r+1}$ is $1$, then put a $1$ in the *last* $0$ (this is just to make the choice definite) in $q_{r+1}$. The new pattern $p_{r+1}$ is now $p_r$ followed by $q_{r+1}$.

Since $p_{r+1}$ is $p_r$ followed by $q_{r+1}$, we see that the sequence emitted is, $\Sigma=(p_0,q_1,\dots,q_{r+1},\dots)$, where $q_{r+1}$ is just the modified second copy of $p_r$ as above.

The above can easily be converted into an algorithm that, given a "black box" that "emits" $0$'s and $1$'s as the values of $s_i$, uses that as input to generate its own sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s, which is the sequence $\Sigma$ as above.

Now this can be applied to any number for which we have an algorithm which calculates the binary expansion. In particular, we can apply it to $e-2$ for which there is such an algorithm. The sequence for $e$ can now be obtained by replacing $0$ in the above sequence with $2$ and $1$ in the above sequence with $3$.